# Problema com leitura de string em C dentro do for()

Tags: c, loop

Estou fazendo um algoritmo para leitura de dados para desconto de contabilidade, porém, o primeiro dado que tenho que ler é o nome. Funcionou tudo perfeitamente, mas, tenho que limitar a 10 "pessoas" para preencher os dados e assim coloquei no comando `for()` toda a estrutura do algoritmo. O problema é que, após receber iniciar a repetição novamente, ele não deixa preencher o nome novamente, pulando direto para o próximo dado que é uma `var` `int`. Tentei com o `while()` mas também não funcionou. Alguém saberia o que poder ser?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int count;
    int salario, cpf, depend, salmin, renda, faixa1, faixa2, faixa3, faixa4;
    char contrib[61];
    float irrf, impdepen, desctot;
    
    
    for (count = 1; count <= 10; count++){
        
            printf("CONTRIBUINTE %i", count);
                    
            printf("\n\nINFORMAR O NOME DO CONTRIBUINTE:\n");
            fgets(contrib,61,stdin);
            
            printf("INFORMAR O CPF DO CONTRIBUINTE:\n");
            scanf("%i", &cpf);
            
            printf("INFORMAR A RENDA DO CONTRIBUINTE:\n");
            scanf("%i", &salario);
            
            printf("INFORMAR O NUMERO DE DEPENDENTES DO CONTRIBUINTE:\n");
            scanf("%i", &depend);
            
            printf("INFORMAR O VALOR DO SALARIO MINIMO ATUAL:\n");
            scanf("%i", &salmin);
            
            impdepen = depend * 0.046 * salmin;
            faixa1 = salmin * 2;
            faixa2 = salmin * 3;
            faixa3 = salmin * 5;
            faixa4 = salmin * 7;
            
            if (salario > 0 && salario < faixa1){
                printf("CONTRIBUINTE ISENTO DE DESCONTO\n\n");
            }else if (salario > faixa1 && salario <= faixa2) {
                irrf = salario * 0.05;
                desctot = irrf - impdepen;
                printf("CONTRIBUINTE %s\n PORTADOR DO CPF: %i\nTENDO %i DEPENDENTES\nCOM RENDA DECLARADA DE %i REAIS\nTEM DESCONTO DE %.2f REAIS COM BASE NO CALCULO DE DESCONTO\n\n", contrib, cpf, depend, salario, desctot);
            }else if (salario > faixa2 && salario <= faixa3) {
                irrf = salario * 0.1;
                desctot = irrf - impdepen;
                printf("CONTRIBUINTE %s\n PORTADOR DO CPF: %i\nTENDO %i DEPENDENTES\nCOM RENDA DECLARADA DE %i REAIS\n TEM DESCONTO DE %.2f REAIS COM BASE NO CALCULO DE DESCONTO\n\n", contrib, cpf, depend, salario, desctot);
            }else if (salario > faixa3 && salario <= faixa4) {
                irrf = salario * 0.15;
                desctot = irrf - impdepen;
                printf("CONTRIBUINTE %s\n PORTADOR DO CPF: %i\nTENDO %i DEPENDENTES\nCOM RENDA DECLARADA DE %i REAIS\nTEM DESCONTO DE %.2f REAIS COM BASE NO CALCULO DE DESCONTO\n\n", contrib, cpf, depend, salario, desctot);
            }else if (salario > faixa4) {
                irrf = salario * 0.2;
                desctot = irrf - impdepen;
                printf("CONTRIBUINTE %s\n PORTADOR DO CPF: %i\nTENDO %i DEPENDENTES\nCOM RENDA DECLARADA DE %i REAIS\nTEM DESCONTO DE %.2f REAIS COM BASE NO CALCULO DE DESCONTO\n\n", contrib, cpf, depend, salario, desctot);
            }
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Desde já grato pela atenção!

Comment: O código deve estar entre ``` e não '''.

Comment: O velho e conhecido problema do caractere fim de linha que permanece no buffer de entrada fazendo com que, no seu caso, a leitura da string `contrib` considere apenas este caractere e tenha comprimento zero. Veja questão 12.26b em: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/